# Is a Giant TCX W wrong for me if I want to use it for around town and occasional long rides?

Tags: cyclocross

I'm looking for a bike to ride mainly around town and hope to get up to doing longer rides (maybe Cycle Oregon).  A local bike shop is selling a Giant TCX W cyclocross for $950 (reg price $1,900).  I test rode it and like it.  Since I'm not doing cyclocross, is this the wrong bike for me?  I generally don't like the real racing road bikes as I don't like to bend over that much. Thanks.

Comment: Just because a bike is labeled as something doesn't mean it only applies to that field - a lot of people use cyclocross-ish bikes as commuters (though often, these bikes are a bit more tuned to commuting with a more relaxed geometry and component spec, e.g. Trek Crossrip). The most important thing is bike fit. You may also want to consider something marketed as a tourer (such as the Trek 520) which will be less agile but have good of rack+fender+water bottle mounts and what not. Only you (possibly with LBS help) can determine if this bike is right for you.

Comment: Assuming you're going to be riding on the road, you might want to consider changing to slicker tyres, but otherwise there's nothing wrong with this bike. Giant are a good make, it sounds like that's a really good price, so as long as it feels comfortable to ride you should be fine.

Comment: Also, note that the price of a bike isn't the only thing. You still need a good lock and helmet at the minimum. And look at this thread: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6497/can-i-use-a-cyclocross-bike-for-regular-road-biking-purposes?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that cyclocross bikes are basically road bikes with a bit of knobby on the tire. I recently purchased a [Raleigh Roper](http://www.raleighusa.com/bikes-road-cyclocross-roper) to use as a daily commuter. I went with the cyclocross style because the slight knobby lets me leave the hard-pack every once in a while. Also, there are numerous bosses to mount a rack, bottle cage, pump, etc. If you're looking at graduating to the Cycle Oregon week ride, you can always get a road/touring set of wheels to swap out. Or, the cheaper alternative is to just get a set of road tires to swap onto your wheels when you want to tackle the longer 100% pavement routes.

Also, as @Batman mentioned, the most important thing is bike fit. I test rode a number of bikes at my local shops before settling on the Roper. Some bikes with the exact same setup felt slower and cumbersome while others felt twitchy and uncontrollable. It all comes down to what fits you and your style best. Everything else can be upgraded.

Comment: Cyclocross bicycle's geometry is usually different than that of a road bike's. CX bike also has a higher bottom bracket, cable routing on top tube is not on the bottom of top tube to be able to shoulder the bike.

Comment: @Akshay is correct. The CX geometry also typically includes a longer wheelbase and a more upright riding position.

Comment: I have the wingspan of a condor, so I naturally land on the horns on my Roper. But, I do spend quite a bit of time in the drops once I get up to speed. I just added a rear rack today using the existing threaded bosses. I'm looking at stringing my front wheel with a dynamo hub, so I don't have to worry about constantly charging my light batteries.

Comment: upvoted the above comment for "wingspan of a condor" which made me LOL